Invalid_URL Error occur while installing axios through npm using react js
Whenever I try to install any package through npm given error generates, even I'm in the right directory, also npm config list generates which is fine. Then why I faces this issue
When I try to update npm through npm install -g npm@latest, then again same error. It is not installing any kind of package there. What should I do????
PS C:\xampp\htdocs\bs-pos-system\pos-frontend-react> npm i axios
npm ERR! code ERR_INVALID_URL
npm ERR! Invalid URL

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\iAT\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-04-29T05_40_03_072Z-debug-0.log
